# how to use react-big-calendar View type with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-big-calendar

The following code sets the view as 'week' or Views.WEEK and works fine in plain js. But in typescript I have exceptions and I don't know how to solve it

```
import { Calendar, Views, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

type CourseBookProps = {
loginStatus?: string;
};

const KinderCalendar: React.FC<CourseBookProps> = ({ loginStatus }) => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(2015, 3, 1))


    const [view, setView] = useState(Views.WEEK);
    // 'Views' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
    const [view, serView] = useState('week'); 
    // "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps<never, object> | Readonly<CalendarProps<never, object>>): Calendar<never, object>', gave the following error.\n    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'View | undefined'.\n  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarProps<never, object>, context: any): Calendar<never, object>', gave the following error.\n    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'View | undefined'.",


    const onNavigate = useCallback((newDate) => setDate(newDate), [setDate])
    return(
        <Calendar
                date={date}
                events={[]}
                localizer={localizer}
                onNavigate={onNavigate}
                onView={onView}
                view={view}
        />)
}
```

Types from react-big-calendar shows that View is

```
export type View = 'month' | 'week' | 'work_week' | 'day' | 'agenda';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Views` constant of the library is not correctly typed. So you have to do this yourself:

```
import { type View, Views } from 'react-big-calendar';

// ...

  const [view, setView] = useState(Views.WEEK as View);

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, im getting 'Views' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Should I enable something? (Sorry im new to ts)

Comment: Did you maybe write `import type ...`? In TS you have types and you have actual JS code like everything you define with e.g. "const" or "let". To be more precise I will update my response to make this more clear. Please check how you import the data.